# ¿Cómo crear Toolbar con items selecionables en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Cómo se puede realizar un menu deslizable `drop-down` con los elementos `items` permite selección `check`

Más o menos foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para crear ese menú sigo el [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/implement-grouped-checkbox-on-action.html)

Pero con la particularidad que permite más de una selección `checkbox`

**Update**

Lo que permite más de una selección ya lo tengo solventado con:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="toolbar.test.dev.testtoolbar.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/selecta"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Selection A"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/selectb"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Selection B" />
        <item android:id="@+id/selectc"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Selection C" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

y en MainActivity es donde intercambio el estado del `check`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    boolean isChecked;


    switch (id) {
        case R.id.selecta:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "A Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.selectb:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "B Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.selectc:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "C Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Pero me encuentro que si roto el dispositivo no se guardan los `checks`, alguna alternativa? no quiero recurrir a  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` si no mejor implementarlo con `onSaveInstanceState` pero no ser como guardar la estructura del grupo de menús con los items selectables

Comment: cual es la pregunta? no deberias andar cambiandola .... la primera (la del titulo) **ya se resolvió**, debes marcar como correcta la solución y crear una nueva pregunta para lo que quieras preguntar ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un menú con un subgrupo que sus elementos pueden seleccionarse como si fueran `radioButtons`

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/map_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_layer"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/map_types_group"
            android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/map_terrain"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/map_terrain"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/map_normal"
                android:orderInCategory="2"
                android:checked="true"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/map_normal"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/map_hybrid"
                android:orderInCategory="3"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/map_hybrid"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

y en el `onOptionsItemSelected` se puede activar o desactivar.

```
item.setChecked(true);
```